# Merge hashes nested within array while using distinct keys only

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge, hashmap

I have a huge array (40.000+ elements) of names with the following structure:

```
names = [
  {"Aabjørn"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"danish"}},
  {"Aagot"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"swedish"}},
  {"Aagot"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"norwegian"}},
  {"Aagot"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
  {"Aake"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"finnish"}},
  {"Aake"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"finnish"}}]
```

My goal is to only keep one key (the actual name) while merging the nested data so the array looks like this:

```
new_names_array = [
  {"Aabjørn"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"danish"}},
  {"Aagot"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>["swedish", "norwegian", "danish"]}},
  {"Aake"=>{:gender=>["male", "female"], :nationality=>"finnish"}},
]
```

How can I iterate through this array and merge its values in this manner?

Comment: Is your hash format is exactly what you have given..?

Comment: yes it is. Your solution seems to work fine!

Comment: But 40000 entries are too much to process by my answer. :-)

Comment: @Severin I would reconsider your data structure what you're trying to do appears to be logically flawed. Your data is easily corrupted in the scheme you have described.

Comment: I only have it in that form to convert it to YAML, so this is not the final format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do :

```
merge_ary = names.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.map do |k,v|
  { k => v.inject({:gender => '', :nationality => ''}) do |new_hash,inner_hash|
    new_hash.merge(inner_hash[k]) do |key,o,n|
      if o == n or o.empty?
        n
      elsif o != n 
        [o,n].flatten.uniq
      end
    end
  end }
end

merge_ary
# => [{"Aabjørn"=>{:gender=>"male", :nationality=>"danish"}},
#     {"Aagot"=>
#       {:gender=>"female", :nationality=>["swedish", "norwegian", "danish"]}},
#     {"Aake"=>{:gender=>["male", "female"], :nationality=>"finnish"}}]
```